# How to serialize only certain elements of M2M set of the object being serialized?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I have these models:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)


class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='members', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField()
```

And these serializers:

```py
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'


class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # some field defintions here

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = '__all__'
```

And view:

```py
class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
```

Now what I want to do basically, is not return "members" of `Group` that has `is_deleted` set to `True`.

So if I have a `Group` with 3 `Member` where 1 has `is_deleted` set to `True`, I want my serializer to return the `Group` with 2 `Member`s.

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can override the members field in the `GroupSerializer` to return a filtered queryset

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_members(self, obj):
        qs = Members.objects.filter(group=obj, is_deleted=True)
        serialized = MemberSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return serialized.data

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'
```

This will return the member objects with `is_deleted=True` for the specific group.

Answer (score 0):

Use serializer method field in members serializer
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield

Answer (score 0):

You can  modify the `MemberSerializer` which only return the `is_deleted` false field.

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_deleted_false = = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_is_deleted_false(obj):
        if obj.is_deleted == False:
            return obj.is_deleted
        else:
            pass  


    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'group', 'is_deleted_false')
```